# jQuery datatable server paging keep selection

Tags: jquery, performance, checkbox, datatables

I have a `ASP.NET MVC` application where Im using `jQuery` `Datatables` to show some data.

The table is server paged because I can have more than 10,000 records.

My first column is a `Checkbox` so I can select records. For example I can select 8 records from page 1, then 2 from page 2, then 7 from page 6 and so on.

Right now the way is working is that on my `Controller` that servers the `Ajax` request for `Datatable` paging I create a server `Session` where I store this selections so when the page is served again I can pass all the `rows ID's` and then show the selection client side.

> I would like to know if instead of doing this I can store in client side the selection in an array? My concern is about the performance in the case the user select 8,000 rows.

Anyone has any experience doing this? In case there wont be any performance issue client side doing this I will vote for this approach.

Comment: An array will certainly allow you to add that number of elements, whether it causes any issue on the client-side are probably down to the browser or user's machine.  It does sound like a useability nightmare though - I wouldn't like to be the person that has to select 8000 individual rows over multiple pages!